# Has anyone use Open2Test (keyword-driven) framework for QTP or Selenium?

Tags: testing, selenium, automation, qtp

I've been doing research on **Open2Test framework** which is keyword-driven test framework that can be attached to QTP or Selenium.

http://www.open2test.org/index.html

Basically it aims to replace writing code to just keyword defined Excel sheets.

The support for `Selenium` and `QTP` has been released in 2009 but the documentation in their site are really plain and not written in detail at all. The forum hasn't been setup so I have to send email to their team per question (and their response are not explained clearly either, basically said "just read the doc")

Also even stackoverflow does not have `Open2Test` tag. So I'm wondering has anyone use it before? I would like to hear any story about the Framework. thanks

Comment: hmm waited few days in stackoverflow and not getting any answer = nobody uses it!

Comment: there seem to be plenty of good reasons for that, judging by the source, the commenting, tests, documentation, register-for-download-policy...

Comment: I agree. Actually I got to the point to make it work (simple click and input into text fields). The concept is great. Just too bad the doc is not well written and only few references can be found on internet.

Answer (score 1):

We did implement for QTP.I think its a pretty good.Spent time in understanding the framework and did little bit of customization as well.Can get it off ground pretty quick instead of building a framework from scratch, the best part of manual tester can work on it through a excel sheet with just little training.

Hari